# How do API Data Studio scopes works?

Tags: api, looker-studio, oauth2-playground

I am using **Postman** in order to test the **Google Data Studio APIs**.
I get the following error for the call: https://datastudio.googleapis.com/v1/assets:search?assetTypes=Report

```json
{
   "error":{
      "code":403,
      "message":"Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
      "status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"
   }
}
```

The rights are present:
[image]

And no scope of Google Data Studio is present here to carry out other tests:
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: It's been 2 years, did you ever manage to successfully access the data studio via the API? My error is "The caller does not have permission" I have followed most of the docs out here but still I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastudio` scope to use the Data Studio API. You API client should also be authorized (see [instructions](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api#getting_started)).

Answer (score -2):

The API is not supported by Google at all. You can't use Oauth dialog.